# How do I convert a PHP query string into a slash-based URL?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am a pretty skilled programmer, but when it comes to RegEx and rewriting, I am a total n00b. I want to convert a URL from

```
http://www.example.com/lookup.php?id=1
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/lookup/1/item/
```

where "item" refers to the name of an item in a database that is being looked-up.

I'm using LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to convert the URLs so they are SEO friendly.

Comment: Looks like u fear them.Please grab a copy of Mastering Regular Expressions.

Comment: I would also recommend Regular Expressions Cookbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple .htaccess example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lookup/([a-z0-9\-]+)/item/?$ /lookup.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

This will match any alphanumeric (also will recognise dashes) string of any length as the 'id'. You can limit this to just numeric by changing the regex to `([0-9]+)`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lookup/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /lookup.php?id=$1&view=$2
</IfModule>
```

This one will match `/lookup/123/some-text/` to `/lookup.php?id=123&view=some-text`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on htaccess rewrite urls! :)

Here's your example:

```
RewriteRule ^lookup/(\d+)/(.*)$ /lookup.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

When you access `lookup/123/my-product/`, it'll call the `lookup.php?id=123&name=my-product` file internally.

Comment: Now the problem is that other pages that follow the format don't work. I want to get another page
http://www.example.com/category.php?id=1
to appear as
http://www.example.com/category/1/name/

Comment: What if the website is in subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect from the old URL to the new? Or are you looking to read in those "friendly" URLs and then have them behave like the old URL?

If it's the latter, try taking a look at [Net_URL_Mapper](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL_Mapper) as a way to parse and redirect those links fairly easily.