# Make URL's look good dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a PHP query string into a slash-based URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301481/how-do-i-convert-a-php-query-string-into-a-slash-based-url)

If I have database driven pages with urls like this:

```
http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=1
http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=2
http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=3
...
http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=4001
http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=4002
http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=4003
```

Where the id in the url is used to get the correct content from the database, and the user has the ability to add/remove/edit as many pages as s/he wants.

I understand how to manually use mod_rewrite to give the urls a nicer look e.g.

```
http://www.companyname.com/individual/1
http://www.companyname.com/individual/2
http://www.companyname.com/individual/3
...
http://www.companyname.com/commercial/4001
http://www.companyname.com/commercial/4002
http://www.companyname.com/commercial/4003
```

But how would I do that dynamically? i.e. allow the user to specify part of the url, in this case the user has selected either "individual" or "commercial", then add the id at the end of the url, without me having to edit the .htaccess file each and everytime a user makes a new page, or edits/deletes a page.

Comment: Please provide a link to where this question has been duplicated, as the duplicate link above does not answer my question as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this could be enough:

```
RewriteRule http://www.companyname.com/(.*)/(\d+) http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php?id=$2
```

It doesn't matter what is before /4441, it will always lead to dynamic_page.php?id=4441...

Comment: Maybe you mean http://www.companyname.com/dynamic_page.php not http://www.companyname.com?dynamic_page.php

Comment: Yes, sorry for typo... Should I repair my post?

Comment: ofc not :) or better...i don't know, i'm quite new here :D

Comment: that is the problem, I need it to matter what is before the id.

Comment: Then You have to specify what it should translate into... Should the `/individual/` stand for `/individual.php` and `/commercial/` for `/commercial.php` ??? Then the rewrite rule should look like: `RewriteRule http://www.companyname.com/(.*)/(\d+) http://www.companyname.com/$1.php?id=$2`

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually adding a new line for every ID in the ht access file?

You could accomplish all of this easily with a regular expression. Here's a post that's a bit old but is completely relative to your needs: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/4332.htm

Comment: Downvoted. Answer is too generic. Provide a real solution or just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out -> [Clean Urls](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls)

You can try.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^companyname.com/(.*)/(\d+)$ /$1.php?id=$2
```

Comment: While your answer may be correct, it is always preferable to post an actual solution on Stack Overflow, rather than a link to what could be a solution. If that URL changes, your answer becomes useless. Please provide an actual solution instead of just a URL.

Comment: It's $2 not $1. Or remove the () around .*

Comment: but that means I can have anything in place of individual or commercial, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule http://www.companyname.com/(.*)/(\d+) http://www.companyname.com/index.php?firstvalue=$1&secondvalue=$2
```